# My arrays are resizing on the fly

Tags: arrays, vb.net

If I do `Dim array As String()` I seem to be able to resize that array and put anything in it on the fly. For example:

```
Dim PackUrls As String()
PackUrls = Split(WebRequest("http://" + sPackBaseURI, sPackBaseURIUsername, sPackBaseURIPassword), ":")
```

And I don't get an error and nothing weird is happening with the array.

I did this without thinking THEN i read that you have to specify the size of the array first! Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what is happening in your code

```
'Create an empty string array called PackUrls
Dim PackUrls As String()

'Create a new string array from the Split function 
'and assign it to the variable PackUrls, replacing the old value.
PackUrls = Split(WebRequest("http://" + sPackBaseURI, _
                            sPackBaseURIUsername, sPackBaseURIPassword), ":")
```

There is no copying from the result of `Split` to `PackUrls`. The original content (which is nothing by the way) is replaced with the new content from `Split`. Therefore there is no need to resize the array. You could easily rewrite your code like this and it would work:

```
Dim PackUrls As String() = Split(WebRequest("http://" + sPackBaseURI, _
                           sPackBaseURIUsername, sPackBaseURIPassword), ":")
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign and array to var you are replacing it with the new array, no matter the size. The var now is pointing to a new data of the same type, so no error is needed.

When you assing a array to an array var you are not copying the items individually, but the variable is poiting to the new array.